# How to get Google Cloud pricing details programmatically?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Can anybody please tell me how can I programmatically get Google Cloud pricing details (e.g., pricing for Google Compute Engine, Google Cloud Storage, Google Cloud SQL, etc.) from Google Cloud website?

Does Google Cloud provide the pricing details in JSON format?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the SKUs and prices via the [Cloud Billing Catalog API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api).

For example, in https://cloud.google.com/skus, you can find the "Compute Engine" service id is `6F81-5844-456A` and then you can use the [`services.list` API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22services%2F6F81-5844-456A%22%7D) with the `parent` = `services/6F81-5844-456A` to find the prices.

Comment: why did the json file say the data is obsolete?

Comment: @affhendrawan — it says so itself: _"This JSON data is obsolete. Please use https://cloud.google.com/billing/v1/how-tos/catalog-api instead."_

Comment: I'm researching 2 days and all pricing point me on this. However, I see only services Skus from this endpoint. How about commuting, for example prising of virtual Machines, how to get that?

Comment: @Dragon – from https://cloud.google.com/skus/ you can find the "Compute Engine" service id is `6F81-5844-456A` and then you can use the [`services.list` API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list?apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22services%2F6F81-5844-456A%22%7D) with the `parent` = `services/6F81-5844-456A` to find the prices. Hope this helps!

Comment: @MishaBrukman thank you for service name, this is what I was missing

Comment: @MishaBrukman can you also tell me, if https://cloud.google.com/sql/pricing pricing data is also available in cloud billing?

Comment: @pramodsingh — yes, just search for SQL in https://cloud.google.com/skus/ and scroll down; you will see Cloud SQL listed as https://cloud.google.com/skus/?filter=9662-B51E-5089

Comment: @MishaBrukman ohh yea  thanks, also there only onDemand prices available not the 1yr and 3 yr commitment prices, can you also tell me where i can find it(apart from their sql page) ?

Comment: @pramodsingh — if you're looking for 1 year or 3 year commitment prices, just search for **SQL year** (https://cloud.google.com/skus/?filter=sql+year) or **SQL commitment** (https://cloud.google.com/skus/?filter=sql+commitment) and you'll find them.

Comment: @MishaBrukman , could you please let me know if we can use this link to get price for a skuId .      https://cloudbilling.googleapis.com/v1/services/SERVICE_ID/skus?key=API_KEY

Comment: Hi @WaleedAsif, please post a new question (rather than a comment), so more folks will be able to see it and will be able to answer it. Please also add more details to your question: e.g., what you tried, what you expected, what you saw (including error messages), etc.